# Fuzzy search support

Tags: google-cloud-search

we are using google cloud search https://developers.google.com/cloud-search and there is a requirement on implementing fuzzy search. for ex: if we search a name: sabarish I'm returning the results whereas if we search sabaris(reomved 'h') I'm not returning the results. This can be implemented only fuzzy search but I don't find any relevant documentation on google cloud search. please help me with this requirement.

I tried * wildcard search but it is creating noise something like if I search "Banga*" it is also bring Bangalore results where I want only the name has Banga. Also tried "OR" condition but if we mention * in the search query the OR statement is failing. for ex: query: "(india*) OR (india)" it brings the results matched to the field where wildcard is enabled and none of the results from the location "India". Perhaps we're not getting spell check results as well. I feel it is a basic ask, give us recommended approach.